# Python: Creating big data base with arrays and dictionary

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I am trying to set up a database to be used in python for analysis of physics signals that can be updated when more data are acquired.

I am not experienced with database creation nor handling as I moved recently from ROOT to python for commodity in sharing with colleagues. I used to loop over ROOT files with different attributes (particle name, energy, date,...) to perform the analysis I wanted to be performed. Each of these files contained several signals called events that allow statistics analysis. Currently those files amounts to 20GB total but will increase.

I want to transpose my analysis into python codes but using a data base rather than keeping split files. I should be able to select certain attributes and retrieve the associated signals to performs some analysis. This data base should also be able to be updated in the futur.

I learned about pickle, panda, sqlalchemy as great tools for what I want to do and I tried to implement different solutions starting with the creation of the data base. (Next stage being the search and retrieve of data from the data frame).

Currently I tried different structures to organise the data:

_nested dictionary:

```
dataDict["particle_name"]["energy_value"][...]["event_ID"]=signal (type= np.array)
```

_ structured array:

```
simtype = [("particle_name", 'U13'),("energy_value", 'f8'),...,("event_ID",'i8'),('signal', 'f8', amplisize)]
x=np.array((proton,13.8,...,156,signal),dtype=simtype)
```

Then writing to a file i tried both dumping to a pickle file and json file. I had to use the following encoder for the json.

```
from json import JSONEncoder
import json
class NumpyArrayEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

I don't know why the json file was heavier than my original scattered files by a factor of 3. I thus focused on pickle files which seemed to work more easily. Should i reconsider json files for my case?

My issue then comes on the updating process. I first consider loading the pickle data then updating it.
For dictionary case when using:

```
class NestedDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self: return self.get(key)
        return self.setdefault(key, NestedDict())
```

it allows me to easily loop over new files (files in a directory) that are to be added to the database and I append them to the loaded NestedDict then, after reverting the data to dict type, I dump it by overwriting the pickle file. However, the solution of structured arrays face the issue that numpy.append is using a copy, thus doubling the memory required.

I recently found out that you can use the 'ab' in pickle to append and thus be able to just add to the database without needing to reload everything. However, I am not familiar how this 'ab' will affect the next stage of analysis and search in the database.
And this comes with another issue, if I want to rerun an event and update the stored signal,loading the full dictionary would automatically update the value but appending to the file makes me store another dictionary.

I am looking for advice on structure, on libraries to use and clarification on some steps I might be doing completely wrong. I tried to look at examples online but most of them use dummy examples with csv,pickles tables or dictionary then loading in panda + sqlalchemy to perform search, thus I am not sure how my try will affect how to handle the next stage.

Solutions I am looking for need to cope with heavy final database size (>>20GB) both in writing/updating the data file and then retrieving signals for certain attributes (usual sql examples).